# A four digit number multiple of $ 5 $ different numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

A boy imagined a four-digit multiple of $5$  with different digits. If the first digit is erased, the obtained number is multiple of $9$ . If the second digit of the imagined number is erased, the obtained number is multiple of $11$ . If the third digit of the imagined number is erased, the obtained number is multiple of $7$. What number a boy imagined?

I got number $ 1765 $ which satisfy all conditions is multiple of $5$..

$ \bullet $ If 1st digit erase , $ 765 \div9 = 85 $

$ \bullet $ If 2nd digit is erase , $ 165\div11 = 15 $

$ \bullet $ If 3rd digit removes , $ 175\div 7= 25 $

But i can't find the way to get the solution mathematical way...

Comment: In your question it says when first digit is erased, a multiple of $11$ is obtained, but in your example on erasing second digit, multiple of $11$ is obtained. Which one is correct question?

Comment: Do you know the Chinese Remainder Theorem?

Comment: @cosmo5 Thanks Sir for mentioning..  I edit the mistake..

Comment: @Pip Yes i am little bit familiar to Chinese Remainder theorem But to be honest not know much about its use

Comment: It is a method to solve a system of linear moduli equations. And this problem is just that. The only trick is to write the number you are looking for like: $a*10^3+b*10^2+c*10+d$, and then when you erase the second digit you get the number $$a*10^2+c*10+d$$ and so on.

Answer (score 3):

For a non-Diophantine approach:

There are well-known divisibility tests for $5, 9, 11$ based on the digits.

- A number is divisible by $5$ if and only if its last digit is $0$ or $5$.
- A number is divisible by $9$ if and only if the sum of its digits is divisible by $9$.
- A number is divisible by $11$ if and only if the difference between the sums of the digits in even position and those in odd position is divisible by $11$.

$7$ also has a divisibility test, though not as nice: $10x + y$ is divisible by $7$ if $x - 2y$ is divisible by $7$, where $y$ is a single digit.

So for example, $17325$ is

- Divisible by $5$, since the last digit is $5$.
- Divisible by $9$, because the sum of its digits is $1+7+3+2+5 = 18$, which is divisible by $9$. Note that if we didn't already know $18$ was divisible by $9$, we could apply the rule again: because $1 + 8 = 9$, which is obviously divisible by $9$. Hence so is $18$ and $17325$.
- Divisible by $11$ because the odd digits sum to $1 + 3 + 5 = 9$, while the even digits sum to $7 + 2 = 9$. Since $9 - 9 = 0$ is divisible by $11$, so is $17325$.
- Divisible by $7$ because if we break off the last digit and subtract twice it from the rest, we get $1732 - 2\times 5 = 1722$. Then do this again, $172 - 2\times 2 = 168$, and again $16 - 2\times 8 = 0$. Since $0$ is divisible by $7$, so are $168, 1722$, and $17325$.

Now you have either $abc0$ or $abc5$. But if we have $abc0$, then $ac0$ being divisible by $11$ requires $a - c$ to be divisible by $11$, which can only be true if $a = c$. But that breaks the "all digits are different" rule. So there is no solution with last digit $0$.

For $abc5$,

- We need $b + c + 5$ divisible by $9$: Either $b + c = 4$ or $b + c = 13$.
- We need $(a + 5) - c$ divisible by $11$. Either $c = a + 5$ or $a = c + 6$.
- We need $10a + b - 10$ divisible by $7$.

We can combine the various possibilities for $9$ and $11$ divisibility to give relationships between $a, b$:
$$\begin{align}(b + c = 4)\;\&\;(c = a + 5) &\implies a + b = -1\quad ⨳\\
(b + c = 4)\;\&\;(a = c + 6) &\implies a + b = 10\\
(b + c = 13)\;\&\;(c = a + 5) &\implies a + b = 8\\
(b + c = 13)\;\&\;(a = c + 6) &\implies a + b = 19\quad ⨳\end{align}$$
So either $a+b = 10$ or $a+b = 8$. Now $10a+b - 10 = 9a + (a+b) - 10$. So

- If $a + b = 10$, then $9a$ is divisible by $7$, and therefore $a = 7$ ($a = 0$ is not possible since $abc5$ is to be a four digit number), and $b = 3, c = 1$. This gives $7315$.
- If $a + b = 8$, then $9a - 2$ is divisible by $7$. We could just test the nine possible values, but if we use $a = 8-b$, we get $70 - 9b$ is divisible by $7$, and therefore so is $9b$ and thus $b$ must be $7$ $(b = 0 \implies c = 13\; ⨳)$. Then $a = 1, c = 6$, and we get your solution of $1765$.

So the two possible solutions are:
$$\begin{align}1765 &= 5\times353\\765 &= 9\times 85\\165 &= 11 \times 15\\175 &= 7 \times 25\end{align}$$ and
$$\begin{align}7315 &= 5 \times 1463\\315 &= 9 \times 35\\715 &= 11\times 65\\735 &= 7 \times 105\end{align}$$

Without the distinct digits requirement, $6360$ is also a solution (the only solution with $0$ as the last digit).

Comment: Quick python exhaustive search gives the [same results](https://tio.run/##LY3BCsMgEETv@Yq9BHaJB20pbYV8iXiwTWwXrIqGQr/eJiGX3WF23mz@Le8Uz7dcWvNjcJ/H5IA1HqpqFwJyXLAanYN7znaoZheD0pb6ib9cUxlHCT4V2C/iMIEjGJTiTgKVUGpdJ3ElS4R1KchEXS5bd2d4p3kjiouvGZWUUmxDErAHv6bBxQm4v6y/bEet/QE).

Comment: The above explanation is very helpful for me to solve such problems...

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Sir u got that but python is something totally unfamiliar to me.

Comment: Alexey wasn't offering it as a solution (it isn't "mathematical" anyway - it is an automated brute-force search). They were just confirming my result.

Comment: As far as solution methods go, the Diophantine equation & Chinese remainder theorem method discussed by Pip may prove easier, and is definitely more broadly applicable. I just like the divisibility rules.

Comment: Although no one has shown a misinterpretation of it, I am still worried, so let me clarify that by saying Alexey's search wasn't "mathematical", I only meant in the sense the OP asks for, which I took to mean "by logical deduction". Such brute-force searches as Alexey did are perfectly acceptable mathematical tools.